# Google Analytics Embedded Chart Modifications

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization, dashboard, dashboard-designer

I am using the Google Dashboard Embed API. I currently have several charts on my webpage, one of which is a bar chart. The label for each of the bars in the chart is sitting inside the rectangular bar. This is hard to read and not appealing to the eyes. I am wondering if anyone knows what to add/remove to this code to remove the label from inside the rectangle.

```
 topPages = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          reportType: 'ga',
          query: {
             'dimensions': 'ga:pageTitle',
             'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
             'start-date': startDate,
             'end-date': endDate,
             'max-results': 6,
             sort: '-ga:sessions',
             filters: 'ga:pageTitle!=(not set)'
          },
          chart: {
             type: 'BAR',
             container: pagesCont,
             options: {title:'Top Pages',
                       hAxis: {"title":"# of Sessions"},
                       annotation:{'column_id': {style: 'line'}}}
             }
 });
```